# Flutter- How to get last value from Stream<String> without RxDart?

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc

Need to know whether I can get last value from Stream without using third party library.

The first​ way I tried, when I can sending the value to stream in 'changeEmail', I can store the newValue in some variable in my BLoC. Is it correct?

The second way I tried, is adding a listener, that will also do the same job as above and I need to store the newValue in some variable.

I have SteamController:

`final _emailController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();`

Have gitters:

`Stream<String> get email => _emailController.stream; // getting data from stream`

`get changeEmail => _emailController.sink.add; // sending data to stream`

Comment: I think it's best to use `rxdart`. There are many use cases where it's cumbersome without all the transformers it provides.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but I wanted to know how Google wants the developer to solve such problems as rxdart is the third party. So you think storing last value in the separate variable is good?

Comment: I guess I'd build a class that wraps or extends `Stream` so that it provides this feature in a reusable way (like rxdart does ;-) ).

Answer (score 2):

you can not do that directly. to get the last value from a stream you need either to finish the stream first or to cache every last value added to the stream.

```
//close the stream and get last value:
streamController1 = new StreamController();
streamController1.add("val1");
streamController1.add("val2");
streamController1.add("val3");
streamController1.close();
streamController1.stream.last.then((value) => print(value)); //output: val3

//caching the added values:
streamController1 = new StreamController.broadcast();
String lastValue;
streamController1.stream.listen((value) {
  lastValue = value;
});
streamController1.add("val1");
streamController1.add("val2");
streamController1.add("val3");
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), ()=> print(lastValue)); //output: val3
```